# Not Compile When Using Multi Dimensional Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

The function of this program is to see if the elements of the array add up to be zero.

Some of the elements can be negative, user input will contain 3 integers for each row in this multi-dimensional array.

The program should only start only if integer n's condition is satisfied.

```
#import <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (){

int n;
int myArray[2][2];
cin >> n;
int i;
int j;

if (1<n<100)
{
for (i=0; i!=3; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j != 3; j++)
        cin >> myArray[i][j];
}
    {
        int l = myArray[i][j] + myArray[i][j];
        if (l==0)
        {
            cout << "Yes";
        }
        else
            cout << "No";
    }

}
else
cout << "foo";

return 0;

}
```

Comment: What error is it giving you when you try to compile?

Comment: Why do you need to use a 2D array for this problem? As I understood it, you need to read 3 values from the user in [2,99] and then add them all together to check if they add up to 0. You can do this with a 1D array.

Comment: You have a worse problem than that, when you make your code compile. You index the arrays out-of-bounds.

Comment: As for your question, when posting questions about errors, please always include the complete and unedited error output in the question. (I know what the problem is, but you should still edit your question for completeness. Hint: You use a *condition* that is not legal in C++.)

Answer (score 1):

```
#import <iostream>
```

should be

```
#include<iostream>
```

Next up,

```
if (1 < n < 100)
```

Sadly C++ doesn't like this sort of syntax. Each comparison needs to be handled on its own.

```
if (1 < n && n < 100)
```

And the braces in here are probably not what you want.

```
for (i=0; i!=3; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j != 3; j++)
        cin >> myArray[i][j];
}// looks OK, but made suspicious by the next line
    { //open brace with no conditional attached. Valid, but unusual enough to draw 
      // a second glance
        int l = myArray[i][j] + myArray[i][j];
        if (l==0)
        {
            cout << "Yes";
        }
        else
            cout << "No";
    }
```

Cleaning up the formatting shows:

```
    for (i = 0; i != 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j != 3; j++)
            cin >> myArray[i][j];
    }
    {
        int l = myArray[i][j] + myArray[i][j];
        if (l == 0)
        {
            cout << "Yes";
        }
        else
            cout << "No";
    }
```

The block that starts with `int l = myArray[i][j] + myArray[i][j];` is not attached to any conditional and will always be run.

Not sure what you are trying to do here, so I can only guess at a fix. And that guess doesn't make much sense either.

I do recommend that you always use all of the braces when working with conditional expressions to protect yourself and make the flow of the code more readable to others.

But wait! There's more!

```
int myArray[2][2];
```

defines a 2D array that has two rows and 2 columns (0 and 1). But this:

```
for (i = 0; i != 3; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j != 3; j++)
    {
        cin >> myArray[i][j];
    }
}
```

is going to attempt to access 3 rows and 3 columns (0, 1, and 2). This will compile and exhibit bad behaviour, if you're lucky it will crash your program. If you're not lucky, it will look like it works but quietly break something else in the program.

Comment: The "fix" of the loops (moving part of the code inside the outer loop) won't help, as `j` will still be out-of-bounds after the inner loop.

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes but I just started a week ago and found this great forum. To get to your question, I was trying to find if the elememts of the array add up to be 0,  which will be entered up in the myArray. Since, no of elements will be 3x3 I used the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

you have many errors in your program

some of them logic errors

your first error is when you check for the input `n` the condition isnt right and it will always return `true` `(1<n<100)` instead it should be `(1<n && n<100)` to give you what you expect from it

your second error is the array index out of bounds

```
myArray[2][2];
```

it has only 2 elements on each row and column and you enter 3 elements to its index 0,1,2 in the for loop

```
for (i=0; i!=3; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j != 3; j++)
        cin >> myArray[i][j];
}
```

the array shoud be `myArray[3][3];`

or for loop should be :

```
 for (i=0; i!=2; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j !=2; j++)
                cin >> myArray[i][j];
        }
```

this statement has no condition and not logical :

```
 int l = myArray[i][j] + myArray[i][j];
```

it will be executed only when `i=3` and `j=3` so `myArray[3][3]`

the result of `l` always will be the value of :

```
myArray[3][3]+myArray[3][3]
```

but `myArray[3][3]` is array index out of bounds

so it alway print `"No"`

I hope now you understand your errors